# Javascript method win.validate();

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript lately so I viewed the source code of a webpage that I want to create some page like it. But I don't understand a line of code.

```
win.validate();
```

I searched on the Internet for the method validate but couldn't find anything. Note that the variable win wasn't called but when it was declared like that :

```
var win = 0;
```

So if any one have a good explanation of that method I will be thankful.

Edit:

I figured that it may be a part of the plugin jQuery validate. But in the examples I see that it's being used with properties, but in this webpage it was just called without any parameter.

Comment: Is it `window.validate` or `win.validate`?

Comment: It's win.validate where win is a variable..

Comment: You would need to show more code because `validate()` just seems to be a method of the `win` object, rather than a method within the JavaScript library method.  i.e. you're not going to find anything online easliy unless you know what `win` is/does.

Comment: win variable was just called twice as I mentioned.. And I know that win variable would open a new window(tab).

Comment: In the console for the browser you are using, type in `win.validate`. That might give you the text for the actual function.

Comment: Can you give us the URL of the webapge?

Comment: I tried to type in the console but it returns undefined..

Answer (score 0):

I got the source of the function by typing its name in the console of the browser..

Thanks to @TheDude